# Unexpected cell content after type conversion

Tags: excel, vba, type-conversion

I have a simple Sub procedure which gives the expected value of 0.32 in the Immediate window but gives a "strange" number in a Worksheet cell (A1: 0.319999992847443). Any idea why this happens? How to prevent it?

```
Sub Test()
Dim arr(1 To 1) As Variant
Dim str   As String
str = "+0.32"
arr(1) = Round(CSng(str), 2)  ' convert to Single and round to avoid a "strange" number
Debug.Print arr(1)            ' 0.32 as expected
Cells(1, 1) = arr(1)          ' 0.319999992847443, "strange" number
End Sub
```

Comment: `CSng` --> `CDbl`.

Comment: This is a floating point error --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result

Comment: Correct, that's the floating point issue, so the more correct solution should be CSng -> CDec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it into Excel and the following gives 0.32:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim arr(1 To 1) As Variant
  Dim str   As String

  str = "+0.32"
  arr(1) = Round(CDbl(str), 2)  ' convert to Single and round to avoid a "strange" number
  Debug.Print arr(1)            ' 0.32 as expected
  Cells(1, 1) = arr(1)          ' 0.319999992847443, "strange" number
End Sub
```

*Edit - I done this whilst the people above commented.  It's the CSng, needs to be CDbl as commented.